# Can't connect outlets form nib to source code

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nib, outlet

I've got a bit of a weird issue going on currently. I'm trying to connect an outlet and a nib file, pretty simple stuff. However, I get the following error:

```
Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find a class named className in the language Swift
```

I've tried cleaning (CMD + SHFT + K), deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, restarting my computer, building the project to try and index it, letting it fully index, made sure the two classes are in the same target, nothing seems to be able to work and get Xcode to recognize these two classes are the same.

Has anyone encountered this issue and been able to solve it not using one of the methods above?

Comment: Is the file a UIView or UIViewController subclass?

Comment: Try changing the class of the nib file, then change it back.

Comment: The nib and file are both UITableViewCell's that I'm trying to hook up.

Comment: did you google? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackoverflow+Could+not+insert+new+outlet+connection+Could+not+find+a+class+named

Comment: I had an issue when trying to connect to a class which was not the first in the file. Does your file have more than a class? Also, make sure you are referencing to the right file in `File's owner` (or wherever you are referencing to the file with the outlet)

Comment: Did you set the subclass of the cell that you added to the nib?

Comment: @simplebob if the op is creating a cell then the files owner should not be changed.

Comment: @Fogmeister That is why I added "or wherever you are referencing..."

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a custom view, UIView or any other then just write the outlet code in the class and right click on view and drag the referencing outlet to the superView, it gives the option of the declared variable.

```
@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
```

Here superview would be the view of your tableViewCell.